# Android: управление яркостью и громкостью

Tags: android

Подскажите, как работает управления яркостью и системной громкостью в Android. Я пытался найти примеры но к сожалению безуспешно. Если есть образцы кода или уроки - буду благодарен)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что то в таком духе:

`ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
System.putInt(resolver, System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, value);`

Comment: Спасибо, помогло)